# Infinity angles on sharp corners in graphics

Tags: vb.net, graphics

I am having some trouble with some drawing in an application I'm working on. Whenever i draw a sharp corner with a line wider that 1 pixel my line runs past the point where its supposed to end.

[image]

I haven't been able to find anything to help. The drawings are graphics paths, and are polygons and pies mostly. I've double checked my math and that is correct. My code is as follows.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    Dim pens As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
    Dim pen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Red, 1)

    g.DrawLine(pens, 350, 0, 350, 800)
    g.DrawPie(pen, 100, 0, 500, 500, 0, 90)
    g.DrawPie(pen, 100, 300, 500, 500, 0, 10)


    pen = New Pen(Color.Red, 2)

    g.DrawLine(pens, 700, 0, 700, 800)

    g.DrawPie(pen, 450, 0, 500, 500, 0, 90)
    g.DrawPie(pen, 450, 300, 500, 500, 0, 10)


End Sub
```

Comment: The pen is drawing along the outside of the path instead of the inside.  Either compensate for it by redefining your path, or ignore it.

Comment: You also have multiple GDI Resource leaks.  You need to call `Dispose()` on `Graphics` and `Pen` objects when you are done with them.

Comment: Also, any drawing you do inside that Button Click event will be lost if the form is minimized or if another form passes in front of it.  `CreateGraphics` should almost never be used.

Comment: I understand the Resource leaks and that i need to draw in the OnPaint sub. this application was one i built up to show the problem i was encountering. I didn't want to past over all my code so i made a simple app to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with the `LineJoin` property of the pen and see if that helps you.  You could also experiment with the `Alignment`, `EndCap`, and `MitreLimit` properties of the pen.

For example

```
pen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Bevel
```

seems to clip off that corner:
[image]

As other commentators noted, you need to call `Dispose` on your `Graphics` and `Pen` objects.  For the `Graphics` object, it is best do do all drawing in the `OnPaint` override of the form.  Use a `Using` statement when create a pen so it will automatically get disposed.